# Domain user returns false when I validate user using PrincipalContext ValidateCredentials

Tags: 2010, active-directory, asp.net, spprincipal

I have created a function to check domain user is valid or not and I have deployed  this function to `service.asmx`

in `_layouts` folder

```
public bool CheckUser(string username, string password, string Domain)
    {
        PrincipalContext c = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Domain);

        bool result = c.ValidateCredentials(username, password);

        return result;

    }
```

When I enter proper `Domain\username` & `password`  it return false every time.

I tried with site collection administrator user also it has full permissions to this site.